# How to add a new in app purchase to a project which has already using inapp purchase in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an IPhone application which is having a non consumable in app purchse already integrated.Now i wanted to add a subscription based in app purchase to it without deleting the existing in app.Can anybody help me with the steps needs to do achieve this.I need to do it as a seperate in app purchase.Or adding a product to the existing in app purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add it in iTunes Connect,am not i'm right?

Comment: yes but there are some buttons or action required for new in app purchase.. you get my point, for example I have frames(image app) for in app purchase now I want to add new filters to this, so I will create in app purchase on developer account but how can I get some button on App for filters